# Pointing cmake to a directory that contains a dependency

Tags: cmake, build, dependencies, libraries

I am battling a ***"A required package was not found"*** error from cmake.

Let's say I have software **foo** that depends on the **bar** library.

And `libbar.a` is installed in `$HOME/lib` with `bar.h` installed in `$HOME/include` directory.

With automake tools, you typically can point the build system to bar by using:

```
$ cd foo
$ ./configure --with-bar=$HOME
```

But how can I achieve the same with the cmake tool?

I want cmake to be smart enough to not only look in `/usr/lib` and `/usr/local/lib` for a library, but also in my `$HOME/lib` directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is trivial:

```
$ cmake ... -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=$HOME
```

If you want this to happen for `bar` specifically, you can set `bar_ROOT` instead.

See the documentation:

> Semicolon-separated list of directories specifying installation prefixes to be searched by the `find_package()`, `find_program()`, `find_library()`, `find_file()`, and `find_path()` commands. Each command will add appropriate subdirectories (like `bin`, `lib`, or `include`) as specified in its own documentation.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html
https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/PackageName_ROOT.html

Comment: Thanks. It's strange this variable name is not mentioned here: https://cmake.org/runningcmake/

Comment: Not as strange as the fact that that page still exists! I don't think that page has been updated in like 5 years. It's mentioned here, on a page that is actually maintained: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/user-interaction/index.html#setting-build-variables

Comment: Thanks again. I'm sure `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` was around 5 years ago, and that it has always been essential in "running cmake."